# Figure out which UnitType (liter / gallon) is the systems default

Tags: ios, swift, formatter, measurementformatter

Is there any way to figure out which `UnitType` is the systems default based on the systems locale?

I have an `UITextField` where a user can input an amount of water. I want to figure out if the input is in liters or gallons, so I can setup a correct `Measurement()`.

Or is it in general better, that the user can set this in the settings of the app?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Locale usesMetricSystem`.

```
if Locale.current.usesMetricSystem {
    // liter
} else {
    // gallon
}
```